# prove the function is increasing in $x$ and decreasing in $y$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given arbitrary fixed $a>0, b>0,$ consider $$f(x,y):=\frac{x+\frac{by}{2}}{\frac{2x}{1+\exp\left(2a\sqrt[3]{bx}+by\right)}+\frac{by}{2}}\frac{1-\frac{x}{a\sqrt[3]{bx}+\frac{by}{2}}\frac{\tanh\left(a\sqrt[3]{bx}+\frac{by}{2}\right)}{\tanh x}}{1-\left(\frac{x}{a\sqrt[3]{bx}+\frac{by}{2}}\right)^2}$$

defined over $(x,y)\in (0,+\infty)\times (0,+\infty),$ where $\sqrt[3]{bx}=(bx)^{\frac{1}{3}}.$

Prove that $f$ is strictly increasing with respect to $x$ and strictly decreasing with respect to $y.$

Remark: I attempted to evaluate the partial derivatives of $f$ with repect to $x$ and $y$ directly, but the resulting form seems to be complicated and not obvious for concluding they have fixed signs.

This $f$ arises from its equivalent form, which is the following 
$$f(x,y)=\frac{K}{x}\frac{\exp(a\sqrt[3]{bx}+\frac{by}{2})}{\sinh x}\left(a\sqrt[3]{bx}+\frac{by}{2}\right)\int_{0}^1\sinh(xs)\sinh\left[\left(a\sqrt[3]{bx}+\frac{by}{2}\right)s\right]~\mathrm{d}s,$$

where $K:=x\exp\left[-\left(a\sqrt[3]{bx}+\frac{by}{2}\right)\right]\frac{x+\frac{by}{2}}{x\exp\left[-\left(a\sqrt[3]{bx}+\frac{by}{2}\right)\right]+\frac{by}{2}\cosh\left(a\sqrt[3]{bx}+\frac{by}{2}\right)}.$

Comment: Could provide a context for $f(x, y)$?

Comment: I just added an equivalent (orginal) form of $f$ which involves an integral.

Comment: Perhaps try splitting $f$ into $g(x,y)h(x,y)j(x,y)$ etc and looking at the signs of the constituent functions, and also at their derivatives.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do the derivatives to the two factors, but the sum does not appear to be manifestly of a fixed sign. I also tried to regard the term $\left(a\sqrt[3]{bx}+\frac{by}{2}\right)$ as an entity and using chain rule, but it quickly gets complicated.